# What to name the table in which I list ways to login?

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

I need to audit in the database how the user logged in.  I'm going to create a lookup table (which will be referenced from the audit table).  For example:

```
ID  Description
---------------
1   Password
2   Smartcard
3   Biotrickery
```

I was going to name this table "LoginTypes", but that seems muddy, because I'm dependent on the object's assumed use when naming it?

Next came "CredentialTypes", but I'm thinking there's a better term?

Admittedly, "Login" (as a noun) certainly seems synonymous with "Credential" in this context, so maybe my original name idea is good enough?

What should I name this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it `AuthenticationMethod` (put an s at the end if you like tables with plural names).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options I suppose : LoginOptions, LoginMethods, AccessOptions, AccessMethods, AuthenticationMethods, etc. It's basically your preference. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that AuthenticationType or AuthenticationMechanism might be possible names. Each of the rows are mechanisms to authenticate into a system.

Answer (score 0):

Its personal preference, what about LoginAudits?